# Scala: How can I split a String into a Map

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scala-2.8

Environment : Scala 2.10+
 IDE  : Eclipse Kepler

I have a line 
  `NAME=bala AGE=23 COUNTRY=Singapore`

How can I get it as a map

`Map(NAME -> bala, AGE -> 23, COUNTRY -> Singapore)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yet another solution

```
val str = "NAME=bala AGE=23 COUNTRY=Singapore"
val pairs = str.split("=| ").grouped(2)
val map = pairs.map { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
// Map(NAME -> bala, AGE -> 23, COUNTRY -> Singapore)
```

Comment: I just came up to the exact solution. Nice one

Answer (score 7):

I came up to something like this, but I'm almost sure there is a more efficient way:

```
val line = "NAME=bala AGE=23 COUNTRY=Singapore"
line.split(" ").map(_.split("=")).map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1)).toMap
```

This gave me:

```
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(NAME -> bala, AGE -> 23, COUNTRY -> Singapore)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
val line = "NAME=bala AGE=23 COUNTRY=Singapore"

val regex = """(\w+)=(\w+)""".r
val map = line.split("\\s+") map { elem =>
  val regex(key, value) = elem
  (key, value)
} toMap
```